# Find all intervals containing a given number

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have a list of intervals which might be overlapping. And, then I have a value and the problem is to find all the intervals which contain that value, the value itself being inclusive. 
I have seen several approaches including range trees, KD trees etc. But, I am wondering if there is a specific optimized solution for this problem, considering:

1. The list of intervals is long. (Might be 50K or more).
2. The intervals may be overlapping.
3. The list of interval does not change once we start querying.
4. The list once formed, is queried for a large number of times with different values.

Could someone suggest some approaches to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a well-defined problem that is most efficiently solved using an interval tree (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), [here](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.838/S98/meetings/m13/1d-bst.html) and [here](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CEQQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcbcb.umd.edu%2F~carlk%2Fbioinfo-lectures%2Fintervaltrees.pdf&ei=5aGnUKe6DYrG0QXmvYHADA&usg=AFQjCNFjmRaFR26gkSLwEIQ9LPV18lOfNA&cad=rja)) for an explanation.

I wouldn't recommend a hash table since for configurations with a lot of overlap you may end up storing O(n) segments per entry, requiring O(n^2) storage total.

Comment: Please point to some c++ library/piece of code, if you are aware of.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind about an expensive initialization time, you could use any of the techniques you mentioned to pre-compute the intervals for all the relevant values you may encounter in your querying phase, bounded to a minimum and a maximum value.

Construct a hash table with these results and you will be able to find all the intervals for a given value in O(1).

Comment: Is there some c++ library which I can use to try this? Is it possible with CGAL?

Comment: I don't know about that.
However, I'll also mention that this would only work on discrete data.

As Astrotrain mentions, there is a trade-off: the hash table would only be profitable if the time complexity of your query algorithm is more important than its space complexity.

Comment: In principle all domains that computers with finite memory can handle are discrete... in particular (32-bit) floats would potentially be feasible to do with a few GB of RAM.